# Ignore Zero in Calculate Hash by HMACSHA256

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, cryptography, hash

I use Crypto-JS v2.5.3 (hmac.min.js) http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ library to calculate client side hash and the script is:

```
$("#PasswordHash").val(Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, $("#pwd").val(), $("#PasswordSalt").val(), { asByte: true }));
```

this return something like this:

```
b3626b28c57ea7097b6107933c6e1f24f586cca63c00d9252d231c715d42e272
```

Then in Server side I use the following code to calculate hash:

```
private string CalcHash(string PlainText, string Salt) {
        string result = "";
        ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[]
        baText2BeHashed = enc.GetBytes(PlainText),
        baSalt = enc.GetBytes(Salt);
        System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 hasher = new HMACSHA256(baSalt);
        byte[] baHashedText = hasher.ComputeHash(baText2BeHashed);
        result = string.Join("", baHashedText.ToList().Select(b => b.ToString("x")).ToArray());
        return result;
    }
```

and this method returned:

```
b3626b28c57ea797b617933c6e1f24f586cca63c0d9252d231c715d42e272
```

As you see there is just some zero characters  that the server side method ignore that. where is the problem? is there any fault with my server side method? I just need this two value be same with equal string and salt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As you see there is just some zero characters that the server side method ignore that. where is the problem?

Here - your conversion to hex in C#:

```
b => b.ToString("x")
```

If `b` is 10, that will just give "a" rather than "0a".

Personally I'd suggest a simpler hex conversion:

```
return BitConverter.ToString(baHashedText).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
```

(You *could* just change `"x"` to `"x2"` instead, to specify a length of 2 characters, but it's still a somewhat roundabout way of performing a bytes-to-hex conversion.)

Comment: Jon, I would have expected better than that from you. Any person going from a byte array to a hex string should use the class that has been in .NET from 1.1 to do that exactly job: [SoapHexBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary.aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I wouldn't want to use a class which is clearly to do with Soap for anything non-soap-related, personally. It would be nice if the framework supported a non-delimited form with specified casing.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone else keeps reccomending to use things like using BitConverter and trimming "-" or using `ToString(x2)`. There is a better solution, a class that has been in .NET since 1.1 [SoapHexBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary.aspx).

```
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001;

public byte[] StringToBytes(string value)
{
    SoapHexBinary soapHexBinary = SoapHexBinary.Parse(value);
    return soapHexBinary.Value;
}

public string BytesToString(byte[] value)
{
    SoapHexBinary soapHexBinary = new SoapHexBinary(value);
    return soapHexBinary.ToString();
}
```

This will produce the exact format you want.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is here:

```
result = string.Join("", baHashedText.ToList().Select(b => b.ToString("x")).ToArray());
```

change it to:

```
result = string.Join("", baHashedText.ToList().Select(b => b.ToString("x2")).ToArray());
```